# How do I connect my PS5 controller to my iPhone?

Tags: ios, ps5

I recently got a PS5 controller and want to connect it to my iPhone. I watched a bunch of videos and did a bunch of research on how to connect it to my iPhone but all of it was the same, turn on your Bluetooth, hold the create and PlayStation button until the controller enters pairing mode, and it'll pop up on your Bluetooth screen. I did it countless of times but it still wouldn't work. I charged the controller over night and tried to do the same thing but still no result. I went on setting and searched up Bluetooth, tapped on Bluetooth devices, tapped on switch, and tapped on Bluetooth devices.... it finally showed up.... Wireless controller. I tapped on it with excitement and then it connected... for one second. I tried over and over again but it kept on disconnecting. Before all of you say that the controller is defect: it's not, I was able to connect it to my Samsung and it works perfectly. Are any of you having the same problem? Is there a way to connect it to my phone? Or is this an Apple problem that needs to be fixed?

Comment: Definitely a weird issue. My PS4 controller works fine with iOS, can’t say other people don’t have this issue on PS5. If anyone else has a PS5 controller, do you have this issue?